Pyodata multiple condition filtering
CAPACITY_PLAN = service.entity_sets.CAPACITY_PLAN.get_entities().select('NAME,DATE,CAPACITY')
CAPACITY_PLAN = CAPACITY_PLAN.filter((CAPACITY_PLAN.DATE >= (datetime.datetime(((datetime.datetime.utcnow()- timedelta(days=31)).year), ((datetime.datetime.utcnow()- timedelta(days=31)).month),((datetime.datetime.utcnow()- timedelta(days=31)).day),tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))))
^ How do I modify the above to include a second filtering condition (The current condition returns data from the last month)
I've tried to use the following: "and", "&", ",". They all fail. Where am I going wrong?
for ",", I get:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'expressions'
for "and", it only considers the second condition
and for "&"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'GetEntitySetFilter'
